# Trying to update Linq2Sql table, but some tables in my DataContext have isReadOnly set to true?

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql

I don't have a primary key on this table. I read somewhere this matters.

For some reason, a simple

```
public bool UpdateServiceRequest(RequestedServiceAction action) {
    DataContext db = new DataContext();
    var service = db.tbl1.ToList().ElementAt(0)
    service.requestedAction = action.RequestedAction;
    service.requestedBy = action.RequestedBy;
    service.requestedDate = action.RequestedDate;
    service.SubmitChanges();
    return true;
}
```

doesn't work. The requested Action, By, and Date don't ever get written to the database. On further inspection, I noticed tbl1's isReadOnly attribute was set to true.
so I tried setting `db.ObjectTrackingEnabled = false;` after the context creation, but isReadOnly is still set to true.

Perhaps a primary key is required for the DataContext to keep track of "Element(0)"?

edit: didn't look through MSDN hard enough: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339901.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Tables don't have any inherent order. For that reason, getting the "first" element almost never makes sense. You can only get the first element **by some order**. Like this:

```
db.tbl1.OrderBy(x => x.MyField).First()
```

Answer (score 0):

The primary key is required by SQL Server to know which record to update on the SubmitChanges. If the key isn't specified, the table will be read only. Additionally, if you project out an anonymous type in a select clause, the resulting properties will be read-only as well.